# Permutations / combinations by tuple in Python

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples that I need to 1) sort based on the 1st attribute, then 2) create a new list of tuples based on the combindations of the 2nd attribute which are matching the 1st attribute.

For example, this is what I am trying to do:

```
list = [(a,b),(c,d),(a,z),(a,t,),(c,z)}

# output should be:
new_list=[(b,z),(b,t),(z,b),(d,z) #a list of permutations would also be fine
```

So basically it looks for similair x's in x,y , and creates a new list of the combination of the matching y's.

I've found some helpful posts regarding itertools, defaultdict, grouping, etc, but nothing that I could implement correctly here.  So far I have almost solved it using a ton of for, if, and while loops, but I am sure there is a better and more pythonic way.  I'd really appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import permutations, combinations

d = defaultdict(list)
l = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('a', 'z'), ('a', 't'), ('c', 'z')]

for k,v in l:
    d[k].append(v)

new_list = []

for k,v in d.iteritems():
    new_list.extend([x for x in combinations(v, 2)]) # could also use permutations here

>>> new_list
[('b', 'z'), ('b', 't'), ('z', 't'), ('d', 'z')]
```

Comment: I implemented this and it worked great. Thank you, especially helpful was the permutations option.  It's for a network graph so the repetitions would make the lines thicker.

Comment: You could write `list(combinations(v, 2))` instead of `[x for x in ...]`

Answer (score 1):

```
def tuple_combs(lst):
    groups = itertools.groupby(sorted(lst), lambda (x, y): x)
    combs = (itertools.combinations((y for (x, y) in v), 2) for k, v in groups)
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(combs))
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for the fast response. I implemented the other response (I have limited experience with Lambda so far), but I very much appreciate your help!